# I need help figuring out how to post a single number from a list to the home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, dashboard

I don't even know what this would be called, so I've having trouble googling it.  I have a list that generates a single number based off some safety statistics:  How many days since the last work accident.  I would like to publish this number on the Home page.  Can anyone suggest a way to do this?  Or tell me where to look or what this would be called?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use REST API and jQuery Ajax to achieve it. Modify the code below and add it to script editor web part in the home page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

    //add list name here
    var listName="Minor Incidents and Unsafe Conditions";

    //add the item id here
    var itemId=1;

    //add field name here
    var fieldName="DaysSinceLastMI";

    var requestUri = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items("+itemId+")";
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#NumberField").html("<span style='font-weight:bold;color:red;'>"+data.d[fieldName]+"</span>");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //alert(err);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="NumberField"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not familiar with jquery.  Can you tell me exactly where to put my List Name and List ID?  The list name is "Minor%20Incidents%20and%20Unsafe%20Conditions" and the field in the list is called "DaysSinceLastMI".

Comment: I modify the code above and add some comments.